# How to align vertices with other vertices

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

I'd like to select a vertex, then select several other vertices and make them somehow aligned with the first one by e.g. Z axis.

Here is example picture of what I have - the highlighted vertices are ones which I'd like to align.

[image: screenshot of selected vertices which should be aligned]

If possible can someone explain me how to do it. 
If it is not, could you provide a good alternative.

Comment: I solved using S Z and entering values using the keypad. I do not know if this is the best way, I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to select the vertices that you want to be aligned. Then press <kbd>s</kbd> to scale, press <kbd>z</kbd> to constrain to the z-axis. Then type zero and press <kbd>enter</kbd>. Then all of the vertices will be "flat" or aligned along the z-axis.

Comment: You could also set Pivot Point to *Active* and select vertex with desired position last.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following procedure

1. Select the whole edge loop (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + Select)
2. *Edge Slide* (Select + <kbd>G</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>)
3. Slide whole edge loop to edge you want to align with
4. With the edge loop still selected grab and place edge loop on any axis.

Comment: You must be the newest contributor. Welcome to Blender Stackover.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select verticies aligned with one original vertex on an axis, first, click Numpad 5 to enter orthographic view. Then consider which axis you want, and click another of the following Numpad values.

Numpad 1: Select on y-axis.

Numpad 3: Select on x-axis.

Numpad 7: Select on z-axis.

Key *Z* to enter wireframe mode. Lastly, key *B* and drag your mouse while holding the left button to draw a box around the vertex.